# Intel Threading Building Blocks poor performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, multicore, tbb

i run a very simple parallel for-loop evaluation of tbb vs OpenMp vs single thread. And while omp scales almost linearly, tbb runs around 1.7 times faster on 4x core system with 100% load.
I am using W7 ia32 with VS2010 i5-2500.
The code:

```
const int size = 100000;
tbb::concurrent_vector<double> x(size);
long long t1 = GetTimeMs();
#if 1
tbb::parallel_for(0, size, 1, [&](int i) {
    double& xx = x[i];
    xx += i;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        xx += 3.0 * j * j + 2.0 * j + 1.0;
    }
});
#elif 0 
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    double& xx = x[i];
    xx += i;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {                
        xx += 3.0 * j * j + 2.0 * j + 1.0;
    }
}
#else   
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    double& xx = x[i];
    xx += i;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        xx += 3.0 * j * j + 2.0 * j + 1.0;
    }
}
#endif
long long t2 = GetTimeMs() - t1;
printf("%lld ms\n", t2);
```

And exec times 14.4, 3.7, 8.1 for single, omp, and tbb.

Comment: It may have to do something with chunk size. I don't know TBB but it looks like you're using a chunk size of 1. OpenMP is using chunks like N/nthreads by default.

Comment: just checked on Linux with 24 threads. TBB is fine, it's even a bit faster than OpenMP (22.8, 1.01, 0.99)

Comment: Are you compiling in release mode?

Comment: same is on windows, 4 HT threads with gcc4.9.2 (16.5, 8.7, 8.7)

Comment: Please clarify `on 4x core system with 100% load`. Is it 100% load by this test or it is already busy with some work while you are trying to perform additional  computations by the test?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.
I checked on Linux myself, it works fine there. 
Seems like a wintel-platform bug, i shall report to them.